# If I square a value units of radians, is the result in units of radians squared or is it still radians?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, angle

I am writing a paper on circular motion. A function given is $$T=Msω^2L$$
The units for $ω$ are $\text{rad}/s$. What are the units for $ω^2$? Are they $\text{rad}^2/s^2$ or $\text{rad}/s^2$? If they are the latter, why does $ω^2$ have the same units as those for angular acceleration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radians are dimensionless, since they are defined as the ratio of arclength to radius when you look at what an angle cuts out of a circle. That ratio  is length/length. So if $\omega$ has units radians/second the dimensional analysis treats that as $1/s$. Then $\omega^2$ has units $1/s^2$.

Comment: Can you explain the similarity between angular acceleration and angular velocity squared then?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. That may be a good question for https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cool, thank you! I will accept your answer when the system allows me.

Comment: If you get an answer there please let me know so I can learn something.

Comment: I will post a link for you when I get an answer. Apparently I can only ask a question every 40 minutes.

Comment: [Here's that question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445324/21441).

Comment: And the answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/445333/215115